# Get the value's labels of a tested object (model.evaluate) neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a neural network and I would like to know how can I retrieve the values of the label calculated by the neural network, when I call the function evaluate.

I have search in the keras documentation for a parameter which does that but I find nothing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# Create the array of data

train_data = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0]]
train_data_np = np.asarray(train_data)
train_label = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
train_label_np = np.asarray(train_data)

### Build the model

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(3,input_shape =(3,2)),
    keras.layers.Dense(3,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

#Train the model

model.fit(train_data_np,train_label_np,epochs=10)

#test the model
restest = model.evaluate(test_data_np,test_label_np)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

before evaluate your model you should predict the labels of your test set :

```
#predicting 
predict_labels = model.predict(test_data_np)
#evaluate
restest = model.evaluate(test_label_np,predict_labels)
```

Comment: in order to use model.evaluate you don't need to run model.predict first. Just pass the test_data_np directly to model.evaluate.
In order to get the prediction values seperat use model.predict.